# How to revert Symfony2.6 file/folder permissions/ownership to default?

Tags: php, linux, shell, symfony

I didn't have a very solid server side configuration understanding, specifically between source files permission and ownership.

While trying to solve a 403 issue (whenever I access http://symfonyApp.dev/app_dev.php/)
I misguidedly issued the command:

`sudo chmod -R 777 symfonyAppWebRoot`

to my web root where my

- symfonyAppWebRoot/app
- symfonyAppWebRoot/src
- symfonyAppWebRoot/web etc
- etc...

directories reside...

**1.)How would I get the default permission/ownership back to my symfony app files/folders?**

- perhaps there is a symfony specific command?
- a php shell command? (or a shell file?)

2.) or can somebody just explain to me why I get 403 response accessing app_dev.php (on a clean symfony2.6 install after that reckless chmod .. command)?

Answer (score 2):

Fresh symfony2 project access rights:

```
chmod 775 *
chmod 775 app/ app/config app/console
chmod 664 app/AppCache.php app/AppKernel.php app/autoload.php app/bootstrap.php.cache app/check.php app/phpunit.xml.dist app/SymfonyRequirements.php
chmod 664 app/config/* -R 
chmod 777 app/cache app/logs 
chmod 775 app/Resources src/ vendor/ web/ -R
chmod 664 app/Resources/base.html.twig
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your app_dev.php looks something like this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
//... more stuff
```

Please replace `header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');` with `die("It seems like my error has nothing to do with file permissions");` and see what happens. If that doesn't change anything, read on.

**"1.)How would I get the default permission/ownership back to my symfony app files/folders?"**

You can use `chgrp -R www-data symfonyAppWebRoot` instead of `chmod -R 777 symfonyAppWebRoot`. As I don't know the original permissions of your files I don't know how to restore those permissions, but It would be something like `chmod -R 755 symfonyAppWebROot`